# cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation plugin and PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build

I try to use this plugin in my PhoneGap project and build it on PhoneGap Build:
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation
I added this preference in my config.xml:

```
 <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation-phonegapbuild" source="npm"/>
```

Unfortunately, I have a compile error on the Android version. I read the instruction on this web site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation and its not working.

I added this preference in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
```

I also remove all the other plugins to make sure to not have dependencies problems.

I also try to change this preference:

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22"/>
```

to 14, 18, 21, 22 and I got the same result.

Here it's the error I got in the PhoneGap Build log:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/actions/ReserveIntents;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Does anyone had the same problem and have a solution?

Comment: Questions about Third-party plugins should be addressed to the plugin author. Follow the link to github, and file an issue. Best of Luck

Comment: I finnaly stop using Phonegap and I compile using Cordova CLI and now it's working.

Comment: Alright. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens, if you/a plugin, try to install multiple Google Services.

The solution, which works for me is, to include the following lines at the top of the file build.gradle (Module Android) in Android Studio:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm maintainer of that plugin. Phonegap Build recently made some changes (it supports framework declaration in config.xml) so you don't have to use cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation-phonegapbuild (I've deprecated it yesterday).

Now you can safely use [cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) with PhoneGap Build. Just add it in your confix.xml.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" source="npm"/>
```